# keep-alive and domain sharding

Tags: domains, keepalive

My website uses two primary subdomains when users access content. Let's call them a.example.com and b.example.com.

Say the textual content is located at a.example.com and the images are at b.example.com

when someone visits a page at a.example.com, that one page is the only item called from a.example.com and a few pictures are called from b.example.com

My question is should I enable keep-alive for all URLs regardless of domain, or should I force a "connection: close" header on a.example.com and leave keep-alive on for anything from b.example.com?

I'm just not sure if keep-alive from one domain can be passed to another and I want to optimize my site for speed.

Comment: If you have quality hosting then the keep alive is less important because your server will have a good response time, if you have poor hosting then your server will respond slower. Keeping the connection alive eats into resources, but is good for slower websites. You can spend all day fine tuning this and that but ultimately performance with standard optimisation comes down to hardware.

Comment: I do have good server hardware. I'm just looking into the fact that users can come from anywhere in the world and also hundreds could access the site at once.

Comment: Good hosting will accommodate that, look how poorly optimised some of the top 100 websites are in the world. I learnt a long time ago, most optimisation is hardware, not code... sadly. My last site I spend weeks optimising it, since then I changed my host, made a new website and has hardly any optimisation, and regularly loads faster than 1 second which for some, may class that as super fast http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/b7uN7H/https://www.bybe.net - I'm not saying don't optimise, its always a good thing but only fix what's broken.

Comment: If performance is key, then use a content proxy such as CloudFlare, or Vanish if your host supports it. Then you don't need to worry about things like keep alive, just my 2 cents, just saying..